# Rails app logic internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm develping a rails app that will have separate instances run in different countries. Internationalization takes care of the language issues, but when there are some minor logical changes I'm not sure how to approach. One example would be the payment methods - in each country different options will be shown to the users with different integrations. Another examples would be salaries -  taxes and social securities are completely different from country to country so we'll need to take this into account.

The differences are not that many so in general I don't want to create a different git branch for each country, but I might be wrong about that.

The solution I'm currently thinking of is to have a different environment for each country - "production_germany", "production_france" etc. and depending on that to load a different yml file with all the necessary variables that I'll be needing for this country. Then create some "Manager" class that will make decisions what special classes to load and what things to show on the views(wherever there are differences). For example I can have the salary calculation classes for germany in "salary_calculation/de" and for france in "salary_calculation/fr" and load only the ones I need.

What would be your solution?

Comment: A question before I answer, do the different countries really need to share data and how big differences between countries are you really expecting? If not, then you can use different databases, if not, then you can structure the app as a multitenant app (google for "multitenant rails application"), tell me more and I'll write you more :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the questions. It's not about the databases, the apps will be on different servers, they don't need to share data. But according to regulations, and some local settings, some logic in the apps will need to be changed from country to country. How to do this in clean way is the question?

Answer (score 7):

I would handle as much as possible using Rails' `I18n`. In case you haven't yet, also take a look at [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n).

For your special cases that aren't handled by Rails, I would go about it like Rails does itself. For example, in your `config/locales`, you might have some configuration for taxes in a country:

```
en:
  taxes:
    name: Tax
    rate: 0.065
de:
  taxes:
    name: USt
    rate: 0.19
```

Then you write a `TaxesHelper` module that will use the information from the locale file to display the tax rate. Take a look at the Rails [`NumberHelper`](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v4.2.3/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper) package.

If you actually do calculations with something like tax rates, I would persist the factor in the model where you're doing the calculation. That way your calculations won't be messed up when the tax rate changes. Say you have the following model:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Injected by AR
  # attr_accessor :net_price
  # attr_accessor :tax_rate
  def gross_price
    net_price * tax_rate
  end

  before_create do
    tax_rate = I18n.t(:rate, scope: [ :taxes ]).to_f
  end
end
```

That way your gross price won't change for persisted invoices after the tax rate changes in a specific country.

Comment: Thanks!. I want to clarify  something though, because I'm not 100% sure what's the right way. 
In the uk the tax rate will be 0.065 and it will be stored in the en locale. What if I  want the site to have a german translation? I don't want to use the 0.19 tax rate if the user is looking at the german translation of the UK site. So maybe I'll create a new "en-de" locale which is for the german translation of the UK site. But then I'd repeat 90% of the translations between "de" and "en-de" locales. How to avoid that?

Comment: I guess in that case it's not really i18n any more. The method is the same, except you use a custom configuration instead of "abusing" Rails' i18n. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration and http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/08/25/the-lesser-known-features-in-rails-4-dot-2/

Comment: Also, in your case 'de' and 'en' actually won't be enough since you want configuration for countries, not languages.

Answer (score 5):

Amiuhle gave a good tip on how to handle static parameterization - languages, tax rates etc,

when you need more business logic then things get more complicated, and there's no 1-size-fits-all solution, just be sure to know tools at your disposal and make sure you fit the right one, and here's one more that seems to be a bit underused in the ruby community:

### Dependency injection

For example: http://solnic.eu/2013/12/17/the-world-needs-another-post-about-dependency-injection-in-ruby.html

This pattern is typically good for managing payment provider gateways for example

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  def gateway_class
    I18n.t(:class_name, scope: [ :payment_provider ]).constantize
  end
  def gateway
    @gateway ||= gateway_class.new(self)
  end
end
```

the I18n parametrizes the payment provider class depending on the country:

```
en:
  payment_provider:
    class_name: PaymentProvider
de:
  payment_provider:
    class_name: AnotherPaymentProvider
```

and you make sure that the payment provider class answers to the same public API so for the whole app it's not necessary to know which payment provider is used, just that a payment provider class is interfaced.

Another good thing is that you can create a `FakePaymentProvider` class for testing and development which will speed up your tests a lot - even if you would normally use a web mocking tool such as `vcr`, and you can still use something like `vcr` to test integrations, and just integrations, decoupled from the rest of the app architecture.

Actually, take a look here: https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant somebody already did a bunch of work on that plan :)

Comment: `payment_provider` vs `payment_providers` in ruby vs yaml. Can't edit because it has to be at least 6 characters...

Comment: Thanks, dependency injection seems very relevant! However, maybe putting it in the locale is not a very good option, because it will depend on the language that the user has selected: in every country the site will be running, it will have the native language and an English translation. I think a much better solution would be to store all the location specific settings in a separate file like "france.yml". I still haven't figured out how to start the rails server and tell it to load the settings from "france.yml" and not "germany.yml" for example.

Comment: Kazmin, assuming they are all running different hosts, you will need to have an env variable that tells the system what configuration to run

Comment: Thanks, just got to make sure that's the right way to do it.